# Unwanted backslash added to file saved by java method

Tags: java, properties, fileoutputstream

In my spring project, one of my service classes has this method to save a file named database.properties in disk:

```
public void create_properties(String maquina, String usuario, String senha) {
    System.out.println("create_properties");
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.setProperty("jdbc.Classname", "org.postgresql.Driver");
    props.setProperty("jdbc.url", "jdbc:postgresql://"+maquina+"/horario" );
    props.setProperty("jdbc.user", usuario );
    props.setProperty("jdbc.pass", senha );

    props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");

    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream( "database.properties" );
        props.store( fos, "propriedades" );
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My problem is that the property jdbc:url should be something like that:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/horario
```

But what is being saved is this:

```
jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost\:5432/horario
```

Anyone can tell me how to avoid this backslashes to be included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing exactly the right thing - you're saving a *properties* file, which escapes things like colons using backslashes. From the [documentation for `Properties.store`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store-java.io.Writer-java.lang.String-):

> Then every entry in this Properties table is written out, one per line. For each entry the key string is written, then an ASCII =, then the associated element string. For the key, all space characters are written with a preceding \ character. For the element, leading space characters, but not embedded or trailing space characters, are written with a preceding \ character. The key and element characters #, !, =, and : are written with a preceding backslash to ensure that they are properly loaded.

If you load the properties file in using `Properties.load`, you'll get the original string back in the `Properties` object.

If you don't want to store the value in a properties file, use a `Writer` and just write the string directly.