# value is not getting set properly in properties file

Tags: java, properties, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, properties-file

I have one property file(ab.properties) with below values:

color=orange

storeLocation=./test.json

company=apple

I want to modify the value of storeLocation to C:\Users\kumar\testFiles\test.json

In code,file is the path from where I am reading my ab.properties file and storelocation1 contains the path C:\Users\kumar\testFiles\test.json (which I want to be updated in storelocation). see below code:

```
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(in);
            in.close();
            prop.setProperty("storeLocation", storeLocation1);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            prop.store(out, null);
            out.close();


        }catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

by using the above code I am getting the below output:

color=orange

storeLocation=C\:\\Users\\kumar\\testFiles\\test.json

company=apple

Value for storeLocation is getting updated but

i want C: not C\:  . Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: "I want C: not C:" ? What does that mean?

Comment: oops it seems that backslash character are not taken properly when I posted this query. I am getting the output as

Comment: storeLocation=C\:\\Users\\kumar\\testFiles\\test.json

Comment: so i want C: not C\:

Comment: look at this answer [unwanted-backslash-added-to-file-saved-by-java-method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23581266/2078494).

Comment: I want to store the value in property file and I already used prop.load. so I am not sure about this thread's solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use following approach to ready property file:

```
public static Properties load(File file) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        int pos;
        String line;
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.startsWith("#")) {
                if ((pos = line.indexOf('=')) > 0) {
                    String key = line.substring(0, pos).trim();
                    String val = line.substring(pos + 1).trim();
                    properties.setProperty(key, val);
                }
            }
        }

        return properties;
    }
}
```

And to save property file:

```
public static Properties store(File file, Properties properties) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, false))) {
        Enumeration<String> names = (Enumeration<String>)properties.propertyNames();

        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = names.nextElement();
            String val = properties.getProperty(key);
            out.write(String.format("%s = %s", key, val));
            out.newLine();
        }
    }

    return properties;
}
```

In this case, in `Properties` and in file you ge exactly same string: *C:\Users\kumar\testFiles\test.json*.
I do not know how it works with escape symbols, but maybee this example give you and idea.

In the real life, if I had such requirements, I would override `BuffereReader` and `BufferedWriter` and use standard `Properties.load()` and `Properties.store()` methods.

Comment: I have used your code, but I am still getting the same output. i.e C\:\\Users\\kumar\\testFiles\\test.json

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I am using below solution, which works for me as of now:

```
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(in);
        in.close();
        prop.setProperty("storeLocation", storeLocation1);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        prop.store(out, null);
        out.close();


    }catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  updateString(file);
}

    public static void updateString(File file) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(file.toString());
        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
        content = content.replace("\\" + ":", ":");
        Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));

    }
```